# Where can we add our event data to cytoscape triggered events?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Looking to find where we can insert our own data for triggered events.

I have an extension that use to call `onImpl(events, selector, data, callback)`, but that was back in `2.3.7`.  What is the updated way to add my event data if I want to pass data that can be used with the event?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is not possible to pass data to core events [anymore](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on). But you can do it when you [emit](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.emit) the events programmatically.

I'm assuming this is the [extension](https://github.com/bdparrish/cytoscape.js-toolbar) that you mentioned. If you just want the paz/zoom functionality, you can use the [pan-zoom extension](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-panzoom).

I'm not sure if a toolbar extension would be any useful. The customization of the toolbar with an extension would be very limited. You can create a fancy toolbar, style and position it as you like and connect the buttons with Cytoscape events with jQuery or other similar libraries.

P.S: instead of passing the data to the event, you may keep the data in a global variable and access it from callback function.

Comment: I am the custodian of the toolbar extension for cytoscape, and I am trying to update my code to utilize the updated cytoscape library.